# Can't add admob to libgdx project

Tags: gradle, libgdx, admob

I'm trying to add admob version 11.0.0, changed min sdk from 8 to 14

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':android:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.0] /root/.android/build-cache/f490cf7844530d9720846c8edda880b864f56ec3/output/AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.ads.impl" to force usage
```

should I change min sdk in other manifest files? Did that in android manfest, I have latest updates installed.

Comment: did you change it in build.gradle of android module?

Comment: "The minSdkVersion of android manifest is not used; it is always overridden by the value specified in the Gradle build script"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find your `build.gradle` file of android module

Inside your `build.gradle` file there is a tag of `defaultConfig`

```
defaultConfig {
     applicationId "com.its.adservice"
     minSdkVersion 14                      // <- change here
     targetSdkVersion 22
     multiDexEnabled true // add this to enable multi-dex
}
```

This will override minSdkVersion of `AndoridManifest.xml` file